How to make a forwarding reference for arrays of items?
I am learning right now about generic programming in C++ and I am trying to figure out how to forward reference an array of items.
I have managed to do perfect forwarding for regular items:
template<typename T>
void do_something(T &&item) {...}

And I have managed to pass an array reference to a template function:
template<typename T, unsigned int L>
void do_something(T (&arr)[L]) {...}

int main()
{
  int array[] = {1,2,3};
  do_something(array);
}

// works perfectly fine

And I can also pass an array as an rvalue:
template<typename T, unsigned int L>
void do_something(T (&&arr)[L]) {...}

int main()
{
  do_something({1,2,3});
}

// also works

The compiler can deduce the types for all of those examples.
I thought that the last function I have provided could accept both an rvalue and an lvalue (as done by the first one), but the compiler raises an error when it is provided with lvalues.
Is there any way of making a single template function such that it can accept both rvalue and lvalues of arrays without overloading it? (While the compiler can still deduce the types)

Why would you need 2 functions if there implementation is the same. Do you want a different overload for arrays and other types? In this case, you may use concepts I think. Besides it would be easier with std::array than plain arrays.

@Eljay There are no "move references" in C++. There are only lvalue and rvalue references. A forwarding reference is just an rvalue reference "to a template parameter", such as T&&. Based on what T is then substituted for, this T&& becomes either an lvalue or rvalue reference (for a particular type).

@Oersted It is an exercise in using templates. I am trying to implement a Matrix class, so I want it to return a List class referencing some items in the Matrix. However, I want List to be able to have it's own data if needed.

It looks like common template mistake of defining type of template to strictly. If void do_something(T &&item) {...} does job for you, leave it like it is. Do you have some exceptions, special cases for some types - so implementation of template has to be altered? If not do not make this over-complicated.

In you case, if you don't mutate content, you can take by const reference, as temporary can bind to it:
template <typename T, st::size_t N>
void do_something(const T (&arr)[N]) {/*...*/}

Else, you might use template<typename T> void do_something(T&& item) and dispatch inside it:
template<typename T> void do_something(T&& item)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>) {
        constexpr std::size_t N = std::extend_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        using Extent = std::remove_extent_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        // std::remove_reference_t<T> is Extent[N]
        constexpr bool is_lvalue_ref = std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>;
        // ...
    }
}


Is there a way to accept and modify item without using c++17 features? (The computer I work on has C++14...

Without if constexpr (C++17), overload is the way to go. One can call the other.

@Jarod42 You should replace all those repeated std::remove_reference_t<T> with a using alias
